# Can I backup my entire Ubuntu installation to ISO DVD?

Tags: backup

This is the third time I have installed Ubuntu on my pc along with Windows 7, but every time I install, I have to upgrade all packages. (Almost 300 - 400 Mb). Is it possible to make a bootable DVD of my current installation so that I don't have to upgrade all the packages next time?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you reinstalling so often? That you do suggests a deeper issue.

Comment: Actually... I am not an expert of ubutu. I was installing/removing some packages, and i don't know what i do wrong in that process.. but every time i end up in some system corruption :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/) is a backup tool that creates your own distro, an .iso as a live CD to install on another machine.  This can include all your data, and you can select whether to include the home folder or not.  Here is the [Remastersys sourceforge page](http://remastersys.sourceforge.net/index.html) .
I hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying this option first it looks great so far. Thanks..

Comment: Some thing is really wrong... It just shutdowns my pc, and my pc doesn't starts after then... for almost 30 mins.. I tried it 2 times... and now i am really in very confusion to use it or not.. what if it crashed my DISK .. :( :(

Comment: uhm, i can't tell whats going wrong there. at which stage does it shutdown exactly?

Comment: when the remastersys starts copying files.. and there are arround 91000 files to copy..

Comment: which distro you are using? and which version of remaster sys ? did you choose the distro option?

Comment: I Chossed the Distcdfs option.. I  can't go to ubuntu any more.. it is not starting.. i am on windows currently. (My system is dual boot)

Comment: i think something wrong with your system. it crashes with system corruption as you said.and i don't know why the remastersys crashed your ubuntu.i'm not an expert, so unfortunately i can't help. but just to be sure.. i ran the distcdfs here...and it worked for me. i suggest to ask a new question, with all the details of the case. hopefully you will solve this up.

Comment: I have been working on it. now I have reset my Bios and installed the 11.04 Beta. And yesterday night I reinstalled it and startedt he processes again. :) I finished successfully. but one thing i noticed was that CUP (1&2) both were in  100% usage for more than 70% of process time. is it normal ?

Comment: yes i guess! it is normal. it requires a cpu high usage. congrats.

Answer (score 2):

While not directly related to backing up your system to DVD ISO media, you should have a look at the excellent community documentation for backing up your Ubuntu system. [Backup Your System](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem)

Answer (score 0):

You could also clone you whole system with [`dd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dd). See the following link for more details: http://www.backuphowto.info/linux-backup-hard-disk-clone-dd

Comment: I don't think this is what he is asking for. Also, you alway shave to be very careful when using dd. I wiped disks with this tool.