# Is it possible to produce an ISO image of my current installed Ubuntu OS?

Tags: compiling, iso

I am running `Ubuntu 12.04 TLS`. Is there a way to produce an ISO installable image of my current system  so as I could burn the image on a CD and be able to install it on an other laptop  ? 
I tried `Remastersys` and several other tools: all of them produce and ISO image which I can not install but only boot with.

Comment: It is possible to backup installed programme by **APTonCD** and restore when required. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/APTonCD

Answer (score 1):

[Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/)is a backup tool that creates your own distro, an .iso as a live CD to install on another machine. This can include all your data, and you can select whether to include the home folder or not. Here is the [Remastersys sourceforge](http://remastersys.sourceforge.net/index.html) page .
I hope this helps.

Ref:[Can I backup my entire Ubuntu installation to ISO DVD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30012/can-i-backup-my-entire-ubuntu-installation-to-iso-dvd)

Comment: I tried Remastersys and several other tools: all of them produce and ISO image which I can not install but only boot with.

Comment: for my self i use the command dd to bckup the hdd as image file  and for recovery i just boot the ubuntu CD or any linux CD and use the command again to restore the image of the HDD . did you try that >> or you need exactly the ISO file ?

Comment: I want to produce an ISO image file in order to be install it later on an other laptop. That is my interest