# How to make a Ubuntu system into an iso image?(Some tools does not work now )

Tags: 16.04, iso

I have install a Ubuntu 16.04 into the Computer .

Now I want to make the system into a iso file (**not too large,maybe less than 8G**) so I can use the iso file install in other computers.

Is there any tool can do it ?

Remastersys does not work now, instead I get the following error:

```
dpkg-deb: error: 'respin_1.1.0-1_all.deb' is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive respin_1.1.0-1_all.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 respin_1.1.0-1_all.deb
```

Also , Systemback is not well done now.

Comment: In other words, you want the normal iso installer but with customized settings and other preinstalled packages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an iso from current installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/534210/how-to-create-an-iso-from-current-installation)

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes, I am also confused that how the Ubuntu iso  file be made from the Ubuntu.com ?

Comment: @Rahul ,Maybe not work now .

Comment: @PatrickNegus,not work now

Comment: @PatrickNegus http://askubuntu.com/questions/534210/how-to-create-an-iso-from-current-installation,see this .

Comment: Please search before ask a question. Possible duplicate of [Can I backup my entire Ubuntu installation to ISO DVD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30012/can-i-backup-my-entire-ubuntu-installation-to-iso-dvd)

Comment: @MadukaJayalath I have searched it . but the tool does not work now .

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install -f` in the terminal?

Comment: yes !@MadukaJayalath

Comment: Try [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)

Comment: Also have a look at this [link](https://github.com/chamuco/respin/issues/25#issuecomment-230819049) to fix the Respin issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49613/discussion-between-maduka-jayalath-and-beili).